# XML serialization, many Lists of differnt objects in same file

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I would like to know:

1. Is it possible to serialize many List of differnt objects in the same file. Ex. A list of Car objects and a list of Book objects.
2. Is it a good way
3. If yes - some good example (c#). If no - how to do it instead

Comment: This may help, it shows how to serialize/deserialize an ArraList of different objects.  http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2010/01/06/serializing-arraylists-of-disparate-objects-to-xml-strings.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it looks promissing. I will give it a try.